# disable scroll bar on the div

Tags: javascript

I have a div.

I want that user should not be able to scroll the page if the height is more than 350px.
Also the scroll bar should be visible in disable mode in that case.

I want to achieve this using javascript.

Thanks

Comment: Please revise your question. None of what you wrote makes sense.. to me at least :)

Comment: "If the div is higher than 350px, disable scrolling for the whole page", is that what you're after? I don't think there is a "disable" mode for scrollbars. Either they're there, or they're not.

Answer (score 4):

I can't say I completely understood what you want, but I think what you're looking for is CSS not javascript. Take a look at the [overflow property](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp).

Comment: How can I achieve this using CSS?

Comment: He says right there in the answer. It's even linked. Just a little bit more effort to click it.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're looking for [overflow: hidden;](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp) perhaps?

Comment: overflow:hidden will hide the scrollbars. But I want scrollbars to be visible bit in the disable mode.

Comment: That's not possible by conventional means. What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you want to show scroll-bars if they are not meant to be used?

Comment: I want to disable scrollbars in some condition.
If I hide the scrollbar then the page shakes a bit(because page width increases). thats why I want to disable it.